# forced logout after user update

Tags: php, logging, laravel, laravel-4, logout

I have a problem with Laravel 4 framework. 
I am trying to update the user  email , but when I submit the form the info is updated but I am forced to  log out. 
I don't know why this is happening any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$args=array();
if(isset( $_POST['password']) &&!empty ($_POST['password']))
{
    $password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    $user->password=$password;
    $args['password']=$password;
}
if(isset($_POST['email']) &&!empty ($_POST['email']))
{
    $Email=$_POST['email'];
    $user->Email=$Email;
    $args['Email']=$Email;      
}
if(isset( $_POST['username']) &&!empty ($_POST['username']))
{
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $user->username=$username;
    $args['username']=$username;
}

try
{
    $user->save();
    return Redirect::to('profile/settings');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{   
    return Redirect::to('profile/settings')->with('error', 'update failed ');
    // throw $e;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'forced to log out'? You see your application loggin out? Or you are just redirected to login? If you disable your logout route, does it still logs you out?

Comment: yes the application suddenly logging out even i have disabled the logout route this is happening when i change email field for the user

Comment: Try changing "$user->Email=$Email;" to "$user->email=$Email;" - the user->email should be lowercase.

Comment: i changed it and same behavior